# Scripts Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Olá, tenho uma aplicação angular onde estou utilizando scripts jquery para implementar um datapiker e um timepiker, esses apresentados abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um script separado para a inicialização deles, esse apresentado abaixo:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datepicker, .datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.y' });
            $('.select').styler();
            $('input.timepicker').timepicker({ timeFormat: 'HH:00' });

            $('.radio-list__input-wrap').mousedown(function () {
                changeCheck($(this));
            });
            $('.radio-list__input-wrap').each(function () {
                changeCheckStart($(this));
            });


            function changeCheck(el) {
                var el = el, input = el.find('input').eq(0);
                if (!input.attr('checked')) {
                    $('.radio-list__input-wrap').each(function () {
                        cInput = $(this).find('input').eq(0);

                        if (cInput.attr('name') == input.attr('name')) {
                            $(this).removeClass('radio-list__item_active');
                            cInput.attr("checked", false);
                        }
                    });
                    el.addClass('radio-list__item_active');
                    input.attr("checked", true);
                }
                return true;
            }
            function changeCheckStart(el) {
                var el = el, input = el.find('input').eq(0);
                if (input.attr('checked')) {
                    el.addClass('active');
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Porém essa tela não é minha tela inicial, com isso o datapiker e o timepiker só é apresentado se der F5 nessa tela presenta, assim o script iria carregar-los.

Gostaria de saber como faço para esse script ser carregado assim que essa pagina for apresentada?

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Recomendo que vc utilize outra biblioteca de date picker construída pro angular.

Comment: Na empresa onde trabalho os scripts já vem pronto, não posso substituir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do angular-cli você pode instalar pelo npm normalmente e adicionar a tag scripts do angular-cli.json.

```
npm install jquery — save
```

angular-cli.json

```
“scripts”: [ “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js” ]
```

No seu componente

```
import * as $ from ‘jquery’;
```

Referencias:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Para adicionar o tipo jquery para autocomplete: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

**EDIT**

Para adicionar um javascript dinamicamente em um component angular eu fiz essa função que recebe como parâmetro o string do script(normalmente um cdn). Por Exemplo:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core'; 

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

 addJsToElement(src: string): HTMLScriptElement {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    this.renderer.appendChild('body', script);
    return script;
  }
```

E você pode chamar ela assim:

```
this.addJsToElement('https://widgets.skyscanner.net/widget-server/js/loader.js').onload = () => {
        console.log('SkyScanner Tag loaded');
}
```

Comment: Então o problema é que não esta carregando porque ao startar a aplicação, os scripts jquery são lidos apenas uma vez. Por isso quando chega na terceira pagina ele não carrega mais, não carregando tambem o datapiker e o timepiker...

Comment: você tem que por esse código que usa o jquery na terceira pagina. E não precisa do document ready, você pode usar outro lifecycle hook do angular.

Comment: Uma vez que o jquery é carregado ele não e descarregado.

Comment: Tentei add o código diretamente na terceira pagina e ainda sim não rolou! :(

Não teria um jeito de avisar ao angular carregar aquele script quando tal rota for chamada?

Comment: Tem como vc editar sua pergunta pra eu ver como vc esta chamando esse codigo no angular? Tem como carregar um javascript dinamicamente mas e um pouco mais complexo. Eu vou editar minha reposta.